# Hibernate spring integration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hibernate version -- 4.3.5.Final
Spring version --- 4.0.3.RELEASE
I am trying to use hibernate spring to save object in the DB.

In Main class() --- I have created context and passed to the EditContainer class.

```
   try(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml")) {
                        Main window = new Main();
                        MenuPanel menuPanel = new MenuPanel(window);
                        window.panel.add(menuPanel, MenuPanel.class.getName());
                    EditContainer customerContainer = new EditContainer(new EditCustomer(),
                            window, context);
```

In EditContainer class--- I have called. save() method here after initializing service,

```
services = context.getBean(Services.class);
currentObject = services.save(currentObject, objectType);
```

In Servcices class--

```
public Object save(Object object,int objectType) {
    switch(objectType){
        case TYPE_CUSTOMER :
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = (Transaction) session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(object);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
        break;
    }
```

Spring.xml ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

         <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="root" />
        </bean>


    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.dev.frontend.model.Customer</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>


    <bean id="services" class="com.ashu.services.Services">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am seeing following exception :

```
 org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:201)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess(AbstractSessionImpl.java:341)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.<init>(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:114)
```

Comment: This may be issue due to transaction. May be try with adding @Transaction annotation at the top of method at the save() and check if it helps you out.Do not handle transaction yourself.

Comment: No. Same error.
I have changed.

@Transactional
 public Object save(Object object,int objectType){
         switch(objectType){
   case TYPE_CUSTOMER :
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
          session.persist(object);
          session.close();
   break;
  }
  return null;
}

Comment: Can you please provide your spring.xml.

Comment: When using spring and spring managed transactions never mess around with the hibernate.current_session_context_class property UNLESS you are using JTA. Also double check that you are closing applicationContext.Also context should be created only once in application.Try removing destroy-method from datasource bean.

Comment: @user2806992 Mark you service class with `Transactional` annotation and add TX:annotation-config. Remove transaction logic in dao.

Comment: @user2806992 by the way, I believe the DB username/ password you configured is correct.

Comment: I created sample program from the content you have given here. I did face any issue. so my question is if you have multi threaded environment than we need to make sure session is synchronized,

Comment: How to make session synchronized ?